# ¿Por qué AsyncTask en Android Studio me coge un string directo y no un array que contiene el mismo string?

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask

¿Por que el `.execute(url)` solo me muestra la imagen si se la paso con el link directo y no me deja pasarle ninguna variable `array`?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_datos);

    new BackgroundTask()
            .execute("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AyM5sjRpwGk/hqdefault.jpg");

}

 private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            URL _url = new URL(urls[0]);
            URLConnection con = _url.openConnection();
            con.connect();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
        }
        return bm;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            MostrarDatos.this.imagen.setImageBitmap(result);
            MostrarDatos.this.imagen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Si por ejemplo pongo:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar_datos);

String[] imagen;
imagen[0] = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AyM5sjRpwGk/hqdefault.jpg";

new BackgroundTask().execute(imagen[0]);

}
```

No lo acepta ni aun habiendo rellenado ese array desde otra funcion y solo llamandolo en el `onCreate`.

Comment: Tu codigo en ambos casos funciona, lo he probado... te da algun error en consola?

Comment: Perdon, el ultimo caso era con un array, que me he equivocado al preguntar.

String[] imagen;

imagen[0] = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AyM5sjRpwGk/hqdefault.jpg";

new BackgroundTask()
        .execute(imagen[0]);


Esto no funciona y no se porqué, se supone que el resultado es el mismo, porque al mostrarlo en un textview lo reconoce bien.

Comment: edita tu pregunta por favor

Comment: Creo que asi se puede entender algo mejor, perdon por el lio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando declaras el `String Array` debes declarar el tamaño que contendrá y sera fijo:

```
String[] imagenTxt = new String[2];
 // String[] imagenTxt = {"elemento2","elemente3"}; esta seria otra  forma
    imagenTxt[0] = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/AyM5sjRpwGk/hqdefault.jpg";
    new BackgroundTask()
            .execute(imagenTxt[0]);
```

Ahora si lo que quieres agregar es varios elementos debes usar un `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: De acuerdo, ahora si me funciona. Aunque ahora tengo el problema que ese array esta declarado dentro del `doInBackground`, en `onPostExecute` lo recorro y me sale todo correcto pero cuando lo llamo desde el `main` me lanza un `nullpointerexception`. Creo que esto ya es cosa de mi organizacion dentro de la app. Muchas gracias!